# How to staple Apple notarization tickets (without using 'xcrun stapler')

Tags: python, code-signing, notarization

Recently (as of 2023-11-01) Apple has changed their notarization process.

I took the opportunity to drop Apple's own tools for this process (`notarytool`) and switch to a Python-based solution using their [documented Web API for notarization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/notaryapi/submitting_software_for_notarization_over_the_web)

This works great and has the additional bonus, that I can now notarize macOS apps from linux (in the context of CI, I can provision linux runners much faster than macOS runners), or a more lightweight installation of macOS (without XCode, or even the XCode CommandLine utilities, installed).

Since this went so smooth, I thought about moving more parts of my codesigning process to linux, and the obvious next step is find a solution for stapling the notarization tickets into application, replacing `xcrun stapler staple MyApp.app`

With the help of `-vv` and some scraps of [online](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3126-inside-code-signing-hashes) [documentation](https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/logging-https.html), it turns out that it is very simple to obtain the notarization ticket if you know the code directory hash (`CDhash`) of your application.

the following will return a JSON-object containing (among other things) the base64-encoded  notarization ticket, which just has to be decoded and copied into the .app bundle for stapling:

```sh
cdhash=8d817db79d5c07d0deb7daf4908405f6a37c34b4
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   --data "{ \"records\": { \"recordName\": \"2/2/${cdhash}\" }}" \
   https://api.apple-cloudkit.com/database/1/com.apple.gk.ticket-delivery/production/public/records/lookup \
| jq -r ".records[0] | .fields | .signedTicket | .value"
```

So, the only thing that is still missing for my `stapler` replacement is a way to obtain the code directory hash for a given application.
On macOS (with the XCode tools installed), I can get this hash with `codesign -d -vvv MyApp.app`, but this obviously only works if I have the `codesign` binary at hand.

I've found a couple of python wrappers for stapling tickets, but all of them just call `xcrun stapler staple` under the hood.
This is **not what I want**.

So my question is:
is there an (easy) way to extract the code directory hash from a macOS application, without using macOS specific tools.

A Python solution would be very much preferred.
Ideally, such a solution would be cross-platform (so I should be able to use it on macOS as well as on - say - linux).

**NOTE** I've originally asked this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77413013) where it was closed as off-topic. If this isn't the correct site either, hopefully somebody can direct me to the real one.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77413013 (which was re-opened and received an answer in the meantime)